Can I recover the seed used to generate the internal state of MT19937 using the state itself?
Is there any way to extract the seed that has been used to generate the state in python or any other language?
I tried to find the implementation of the random.seed method to reverse myself, I have successfully translate it to python to hide some unnecessary details because it was written in cpython but I couldn't because the seed is firstly getting split into chunks of 8 or 32 bit integers then circularly getting xorred with a constant array and some other constant values, I am still new to reversing a PRNG or anything related to complex method so is it possible or not?
